# Привязка программы к xml

Tags: c#, xml

Есть программа которая черпает данные из xml.
Так вот стоит задача привязать программу к конкретному xml, чтоб программа не запускалась если xml была отредактирована или заменена на другую.

Comment: Сравнивать свёртку (допустим MD5) с хранящейся в коде программы.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Что вы храните в XML? Настройки? Ключи? Что понимаете под редактированием этго XML: любые изменения данных в нём или изменение его структуры? В первом случае можно сверять хэш XML с хэшем "правильного" XML, во втором нужна валидация XML по схеме.

Comment: А что мешает хранить в программе копию и сравнивать? :-) Более того, если вы _не хотите_ разрешать пользователю изменять файл, просто не давайте ему этот файл, делов-то!

Comment: Нужно защищать от любых изменений данных в xml. Зачищать нужно не от пользователя, а от хакера. 
Если я буду в хранить хеш в программе, то есть большая вероятность, что его найдут и изменять, даже после обфускации.

Comment: От хакера? Забудьте. Всё, что на машине юзера, находится под полным его контролем. Он дизассемблирует вашу программу и выкинет проверку нафиг. Вы бессильны. Разве что поместите программу в инет как веб-сервис.